# generating jacoco code coverage report for all sub modules

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, jacoco

I'm trying to integrate JaCoCo in my Play Scala project, I want it to run code coverage for all sub modules in one report.

When I add the "jacoco.settings" to the root project, jacoco doesn't recognize the tests for the sub modules. in order to do so, I configured the jacoco setting for each one of the modules, and then run the coverage for each one of them (see comment out code). the result is one report for each module.

I would like to generate one report for the whole project, any Idea what can I do?

```
object PlutusBuild extends Build {

lazy val root = Project(id = "Plutus", base = file("."))
               .aggregate(common, importer, crawler, ref_webapp)
               .settings(graphSettings: _*)
               .settings(jacoco.settings: _*)

lazy val common = Project(id = "Plutus-Common", base =      
            file("common"))
            /*.settings(jacoco.settings: _*)*/

lazy val importer = Project(id = "Plutus-Importer", base = 
            file("importer")).dependsOn(common)
            /*.settings(jacoco.settings: _*)*/

lazy val crawler  = Project(id = "Plutus-Crawler", base =  
            file("crawler")).dependsOn(common).
            configs(Atmos).settings(atmosSettings:_*)
            /*.settings(jacoco.settings: _*)*/
...
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're using [jacoco4sbt](https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt)? This was [recently fixed in version 2.1.4](https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt/issues/3).

You need to use this setting:

```scala
Keys.fork in jacoco.Config := true
```